# Session Conflicts codeIgnite (2 applications within same server using auth_tank library)

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, conflict

I have 2 applications running at same server. When I am using one application and logging in inside it. It is working fine.
But when I access an other application from same server withing same browser. and logging in that 2nd application. Both of the applications logout. I am not able to do anything more after logging in both applications at same browser.

What I have tried I am giving you details below:
1. Have changed session variable names.
2. Even I have used another external session library that is https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Dariusz-Debowczyk's-Session-Class
and I have also changed

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
```

to

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'session';
```

This is session config in config.php

```
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

Can you please help me out for this issue?? Waiting for your reply. and Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May Be You are Creating Two Sessions data with same name . when you Log into Two Different Project. There force It's Happened ..

like 
$this->session->set_userdata('front_user',$front_user_data_array);

for both Project 'front_user' is same but Data are Different Please Change The Name Of That .

Comment: I have just fixed it by changing session library and unique name for applications. Thanks :)

Comment: I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark that answer useful